# CD/DVD drive will not read discs after Windows 8/8.1 upgrade

Tags: windows-8.1, dvd, compact-disc, disc

I have a Toshiba Satellite L505D-S5965 with Windows 8.1 and HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GT20F disk drive and when I upgraded from Windows 7,  the drive stopped playing music and movies from CD/DVD's. I checked the Device Manager and it said "Windows cannot start this hardware device because its configuration information (in the registry) is incomplete or damaged. (Code 19)." Is there anyway to solve this problem?

EDIT: I got my drive name wrong. I listed my hard drive instead of my CD/DVD Drive. The Drive is a HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GT20F.

Comment: do you see the drive in device manager?

Comment: I see the drive.

Comment: I don't see it anymore.

Comment: It's possible the driver isn't compatible. You said you could see it in device manager, but it dissappeared. Try enabling "show hidden devices". In device manager go to "View/Show hidden devices", then click on your computer name (eg: home-pc), and on the top menu click  the icon on the far right to "scan for hardware changes". Then look to see if your drive shows up again in the list.

Comment: I did something wrong. I see the drive but it has a yellow triangle with a exclamation point by it.

Comment: When there is a yellow triangle with exclamation, double click on the device and type out what the warning or error message is.

Comment: It says "Windows cannot start this hardware device because its configuration information (in the registry) is incomplete or damaged. (Code 19)"